# "It's an honour to see you": Is it dummy "it"?

Tags: dummy-pronouns

"It's an honour to see you."

Is it dummy "it" and is "to see you" a real subject? "To see you is an honour."

Or does "see you" function as an adverb of 'reason'? It's an honour because I see you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *It's an honour to see you.*

Your example is called an Extraposition construction -- one consisting of "it" as subject and the postverbal subordinate clause ("to see you") in extraposed position.

The basic (non-extraposed) equivalent has "to see you" as subject:

> *To see you is an honour.*

Note that in Extraposition the "it" is a dummy element  serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position; the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of "it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the verb phrase.

Comment: And a most everyday construction - "It is raining" being the most obvious example.  What is raining?

Comment: @WS2 Not a useful example since, unlike the OP's example, it is not a reversible extraposition construction.

Comment: My comment refers only to the "anticipatory" or dummy "it" - as in "It's 7 o'clock", "hold it". etc.  Otherwise as you point out my example is that of an entirely different sentence structure.